# How to create usable alias in MySQL SUM subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, date, subquery, window-functions

In the following MySQL query I am able to generate a Sum value but can not assign a value that can be used to echo in a PHP page.

```
SELECT
    invoices.InvoiceNo AS Invoice,
    invoices.invDate AS DATE,
    invoices.invValue AS Amount,
    (
        SELECT SUM(invoices.invValue) AS GrandTotal
        FROM invoices
        WHERE invoices.fKey = 186 AND inv_openClosed = 0
    )
FROM invoices
WHERE invoices.fKey = 186 AND inv_openClosed = 0
ORDER BY Invoice DESC
```

Testing shows a result but the Alias of "GrandTotal" is not working. And there is no error from MySQL to pursue the solution.

Here is the result from the query :
[image]

Comment: I think your alias is in the wrong place. It's on the column inside the subquery, but doesn't the subquery itself need to be aliased?

Comment: Yes, my alias should have been outside the subquery (aliasing the result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of aliasing inside the subquery, alias its result :

```
SELECT
    invoices.InvoiceNo AS Invoice,
    invoices.invDate AS DATE,
    invoices.invValue AS Amount,
    (
        SELECT SUM(invoices.invValue) 
        FROM invoices
        WHERE invoices.fKey = 186 AND inv_openClosed = 0
    ) AS GrandTotal
FROM invoices
WHERE invoices.fKey = 186 AND inv_openClosed = 0
ORDER BY Invoice DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

The alias needs to be in the *outer query* not the *inner query*:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceNo AS Invoice,
       i.invDate AS DATE,
       i.invValue AS Amount,
       (SELECT SUM(i2.invValue)
        FROM invoices i2
        WHERE i2.fKey = 186 AND i2.inv_openClosed = 0
       )  AS GrandTotal
FROM invoices i
WHERE i.fKey = 186 AND i.inv_openClosed = 0
ORDER BY i.Invoice DESC;
```

You'll notice that I also included table aliases and qualified column names.  You can write this as a correlated subquery as well, so you don't need to repeat the constants:

```
       (SELECT SUM(i2.invValue)
        FROM invoices i2
        WHERE i2.fKey = i.fKey AND i2.inv_openClosed = i.inv_openClosed
       )  AS GrandTotal
```

And in MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceNo AS Invoice,
       i.invDate AS DATE,
       i.invValue AS Amount,
       SUM(i.invValue) OVER (PARTITION BY fKey, inv_openClosed) as GrandTotal
FROM invoices i
WHERE i.fKey = 186 AND i.inv_openClosed = 0
ORDER BY i.Invoice DESC;
```

Comment: I will study your answers and appreciate the added information!